# How to include custom files in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I would like to add custom (non-project) files to generate some extra pages with [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

I am (was actually) unsure how these files should be named and how their content should be formatted.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I having been searching quite a lot before I found the answer, so I thought it would be nice to share!

According to this [Doxygen gotchas](http://entrenchant.blogspot.com/2009/09/doxygen-gotchas.html) article I finally found that: you need to add a file with the ***dox*** extension. Its content should contain C-style comment blocks:

```
/*!
  \page My test page
  contents
  ...
  more contents
*/
```

Make sure your custom files are placed in a directory which is included in [INPUT](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input) setting or in the current directory if INPUT is left empty, so these files can be found.

Comment: Markdown is now also available. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9522667/339872) how to use it.

Comment: It will (at the time of writing) accept some other comment forms, e.g. `///` instead of C-style multiline comments and `@` instead of `\`, but it seems the last line must consist of the comment marker (`\\\`) and nothing else.

Answer (score 46):

Just for completeness: there are 3 possible extensions which doxygen treats as additional documentation files: .dox, .txt and .md.

Files with extensions .dox, .txt are hidden from the file index and are treated as normal source files, just without as much source.

Inside these files, you will need at least one [C/C++ style comment block](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html), which you can fill with your documentation.

Files with the .md extension are treated as having documentation using [Markdown formatting](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html). These are treated as related pages.

Comment: As this is still highly popular on google: It looks like nowadays, .md has to be added to that list.

Comment: Using doxygen 1.8.13, .txt does not work. .md works for me.

Comment: @Fabian See the tag EXTENSION_MAPPING in the doxygen configuration file(Doxyfile)

Comment: @albert Thank you. This allows to add txt files, but then I need to choose a language to parse them in and use doxygen comments within the txt file. Markdown files are automatically treated as a doxygen page without modifying the md file, which is what I also expect for txt files.

Comment: @Fabian, I think I understand your problem, in the documentation the possibility for Markdown has not been mentioned . You probably need: `EXTENSION_MAPPING = txt=md`.

Answer (score 17):

For even more completeness, starting with Doxygen version 1.8 (I believe), it now supports additional text files which are very similar to [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) syntax.  You no longer need to use C/C++ style comment blocks. Instead, just write *almost* normal text and make sure that the text file is in the INPUT path, and that your doxygen scan actually looks for files with .markdown extension (or any other extension you choose to use, like .md).

Comment: I'm not positive (perhaps treat this as a question) but I don't see a way to add commands like \dot into a markdown document.

Comment: @pedz: It's been a while since I played around with Doxygen (switched jobs a while back), so don't remember all details.  You can't add any custom tag into markdown. It has to be supported by the parser, but I believe "\dot" is a valid tag: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmddot.  so possibly a) you don't have the right version or b) in your config file you didn't specify that DOT tool is available.

Answer (score 11):

For clarity:

In the .dox configuration file, add the file to the INPUT directive with something
like this:

```
INPUT = ../src \
        ../include \
        ../docs/my-extra-file.txt
```

If the file had the appropriate extension, say like .h or .c then Doxygen would find the file without adding to the INPUT directive. Inside the file use normal Doxygen tags, as in the source, i.e. inside comment blocks, like:

```
/*! \mainpage MyProject - A Brief Description.
\image html Mylogo.png
\section my-intro MyProject Introduction
\htmlinclude about-MyProject.html
*/
```

One can also just use one of the include tags, like the "\htmlinclude" in the above example, any where in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just list your custom files in the INPUT macro in your doxyfile. You can choose whatever name you find appropriate. Format is text with Doxygen tags.

Comment: I tried that, but the file got included as a source file (added into list of files). Using the dox extension seems to prevent this