# Can I have my GitHub Pages index.html in a subfolder of the repository?

Tags: github, doxygen, github-pages

I'm trying to use GitHub pages to host a Doxygen site. Ideally, I'd like to be able to push the generated files and directories to GitHub without having to tweak them at all.

This, however, means that my index.html is in a subfolder of the repository and GitHub Pages isn't picking it up (I get a 404 when I try to access the Pages site). Is there a way to make GitHub recognise that index.html when it's in a subfolder?

It is a project site.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Create a dummy index.html at the root and put this in your header:

```xml
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://repo.github.io/folder/index.html">
```

Be sure to change the destination URL. This will instantly redirect from index.html to your folder/index.html.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe you want to push a subtree. For instance, let's say you have the `build/dist` directory and there the Doxygen site is built.

After building, to make sure to commit all changes in that folder, then do the following.

```
git subtree push --prefix build/dist origin gh-pages
```

It's important that you don't have anything on the `gh-pages` branch, on local or origin.

All credit goes to: https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490

Initially I also thought of a redirect. But redirects feel like code smells, even HTTP redirects. Although sometimes unavoidable, here may be a cleaner solution, and it is probably what you were looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You now have the option to use the `/docs` folder of the `master` branch as the root of your GitHub Pages website.

Answer (score 5):

The [answer by David Jacquel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320356/can-i-have-my-github-pages-index-html-in-a-subfolder-of-the-repository/25327759#25327759) is awesome.

But if you're trying to serve your whole SPA personal blog from the `/dist` or `/build` folder of GitHub Pages as I do, there's [a beautiful dirty hack by Raphael Pedicini](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages).

He suggests that you create a proxy `index.html` page and custom `404.html` page. If your user enters the direct URL of a subpage, e.g. https://example.github.io/blog/, the GitHub Pages server will serve `404.html` with scripts that pass the URL as a set of parameters to a proxy index.html, which launches the SPA.

I won't duplicate his code here, as it very well might change over time.

Answer (score 5):

To use `Doxygen` and `gh-pages`, you need to:

1. Create the file `.nojekyll` in the root of your `gh-pages` branch
2. Make sure you removed `.png`, `.html`, and similars from your `.gitignore` file
3. And finally, create the `index.html` file in the root of your project:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html lang="en-US">
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=html/index.html">
           <title>Page Redirection</title>
       </head>
       <body>
           If you are not redirected automatically, 
           follow the <a href="html/index.html">link to the documentation</a>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

References:

1. [GitHub Pages (github.io) doxygen generated page not found (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185609/github-pages-github-io-doxygen-generated-page-not-found-404)
2. [How to automatically generate doxygen documentation using Travis](https://gist.github.com/francesco-romano/351a6ae457860c14ee7e907f2b0fc1a5)
3. [Auto-deploying Doxygen documentation to gh-pages with Travis CI](https://gist.github.com/vidavidorra/548ffbcdae99d752da02)
4. https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/
5. [Publish Your Project Documentation with GitHub Pages](https://blog.github.com/2016-08-22-publish-your-project-documentation-with-github-pages/)
6. [How to make an introduction page with Doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502426/how-to-make-an-introduction-page-with-doxygen)

Answer (score 1):

Try transferring your *index.html* file and all its dependencies into a new repository and then use that repository as a sub-module in you current repository. Currently GitHub Pages expects to find an *index.html* file in the root of your repository which it can't.

For example, let’s say your current repo is 'test'. You create anew repository say, 'website', transfer your .html and other files which are required to the 'website' repository. Now you need to use 'website' repository as a sub-module inside the 'test' repository.

*Mote: in the above schema you only need to use the 'gh-pages' branch-name in your 'website' repository while 'test' can still retain the master branch.*

A little example tutorial on [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Answer (score 1):

If your index.html is inside a folder in your repository and to deploy it
you can use choose deployment option to `github actions` and then choose
`jekyll` now the important part when you set your jekyll-gh-pages.yml for github action you don't have to modify the file content except for

`source` whose default is `./`
change to the subfolder where your index.html is
[image]

for me my index.html was inside the frontend folder so I did
as above

Answer (score 0):

The question is mainly about having the index.html in a subfolder of the repository. But it is focused on the Doxygen html documentation. So I will also respect this. I had the same problem and it took me some time to understand it a bit. So I will give it to the community and also for my own documentation for later reuse.

As shown by *Agustín Amenabar* in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35956459/5014688) you can just copy valid content to the origin Github Pages (origin gh-pages) and it can be shown for example as web site on address https://ingo-h.github.io/simple_tests/. But You have to ensure that you only copy the "rooted" subfolder (nothing to do for "rooting" except placing an index.html there). This can be done e.g. with

```
~$ git subtree push --prefix build/docs/html origin gh-pages
```

Thanks to [cobyism](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) for his nice idea. Doing this you will automatically get a branch `remotes/origin/gh-pages` in your repository. You can also just `~$ git switch gh-pages` to it and have it local. I don't have a deeper look at it for what it can be good. On my test environment I get this:

```
~$ git branch --all
  dev
  gh-pages
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/main
```

On your Github Actions tab you also find a workflow log `pages-build-deployment`. Looking at it you will find that the web site is build by default with `Jekyll` (blog-aware application). As we will see later, this is sub optimal with Doxygen.

Assuming you have a valid source, with this handmade deployment you have first to push its content and then deploy it:

```
~$ git push
~$ git subtree push --prefix build/docs/html origin gh-pages
```

To avoid the second step you can enable to use the `docs/` directory or a Github Workflow as described at [Configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site). They will trigger the deployment with a push. These workflows create a `Fragment` to deploy that is equivalent to the subtree push. They do not create a `remotes/origin/gh-pages` branch on your repository.

Both options use Jekyll to build the web site from the sources because it is assumed that they are markdown sources that have to be translated to html. But for Doxygen it is wasted performance because its web pages are already build to a web site, ready for use. Fortunately Github provides a workflow template 'static.yml` that only uploads content without using Jekyll. This should be used for Doxygen html documentation because it should increase the upload speed a lot. When enabling the workflow use on configuring Github pages you should select **StaticHTML**:

[image: Configure GitHub Pages]

When clicking `Configure` you can edit the workflow. At the end you find the source path:

```
  - name: Upload artifact
    uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
    with:
      # Upload entire repository
      path: '.'
```

Here you can set your source path, e.g.:

```
      # My source path
      path: 'build/docs/html'
```

By the way, you must be signed in as the owner of the repository, otherwise you will not find the "settings" button to get to the "Pages" configuration as described with the link above. I usually manage my repositories as contributor with all rights but that is not enough to setup "Pages". There is no hint about this and it took me some annoying time to find it out.