# is it possible to change where github pages looks for index.html?i

Tags: github

I have searched alot but I can't find a solution. I'm using middleman aand my directory structure is like this

Project

--Source

---javascript

---stylesheets

---index.html.erb

---submit.html.erb

When I deployed my project on github and tried to access the site it's giving me 404 error that it cannot find the index.html page can you tell me that if there is a way I can change the link to index.html

I have tried this solution but this does not works

[Can I have my Github Pages index.html in a subfolder of the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320356/can-i-have-my-github-pages-index-html-in-a-subfolder-of-the-repository)

Here's the link to my git repo

https://github.com/Gardezi1/Gardezi1.github.io

Comment: Have you run `bundle exec middleman bulid` before uploading to github pages? After building into a subdirectory, you can use the trick in the question you linked to to redirect the user there.

Comment: no I did'nt ran that command

Comment: Then you probably want to read https://middlemanapp.com/basics/build_and_deploy/ :)