# GitHub Pages - Project Site content under a Subfolder

Tags: github, github-pages

I have created a repository in my GitHub account and followed the instruction found [here](https://pages.github.com/). However the problem is that the HTML files in my repository are placed within a subfolder.

So the current scheme is `https://UserName.GitHub.io/Repository` and under `Repository` I have another folder called `site` and under this directory I have got the `index.html` file.

I did try going by the solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320356/can-i-have-my-github-pages-index-html-in-a-subfolder-of-the-repository) by creating an `index.html` file in the *repository* that redirects to the `site` directory.

The content of which is:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://UserName.github.io/Repository/site" />`

Now when I try the url `https://UserName.GitHub.io/Respository` I get redirected to `https://UserName.GitHub.io/Repository/site` but I am still getting the *404 Page not found* error.

Comment: Could you update the post with links to your Github repos so I can inspect the HTML redirects?

Comment: @ StephenG Thank you for asking Stephen, I actually have ended up creating two different repositories for the website and I no longer am using the redirection method which was unfavorable to many search engines.