# Github pages returns readme file instead of index.html. Can't host my react project

Tags: github, github-pages

I have problem with host my react project on gh-pages.
i Have my repo on github ---->  [GitHub repo](https://github.com/lukasz9210/todos-app) 
My page return readme file instead of indx.html (public/index.html). --->  [My Page](https://lukasz9210.github.io/todos-app/)

What should i do to my page with my react app works correctly?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320356/can-i-have-my-github-pages-index-html-in-a-subfolder-of-the-repository

Comment: I'd suggest [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41773908/1229023)

Comment: I've answered this question for GitHub user pages here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351598/why-is-my-create-react-app-showing-readme-md-not-index-html/47999475#47999475

Answer (score 9):

In my experience, it was simply a latency issue. When I initially committed index.html (in the root of the repo), myorg.github.io continued to serve README.md. After a few hours, I returned and tried it again - lo and behold my index.html was served. Because of the time I was away, I can't make a guess about how long it takes github pages to update.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I was about to apply the change proposed by another answer, but now after waiting merely some 5 minutes, my README.md is server by `http://my_username.github.io/my_project`.

Comment: You can also try clearing the cookies, and then refresh the page.

Answer (score 6):

I have added front matter part to the readme.md and it fixed the problem.

```
---
permalink: /index.html
---
```

After this it shows index.html instead of readme. I have found this solution also helps for custom 404 pages. https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is in how you have deployed your site, you should deploy your target index.html to gh-pages
Check this out:

https://medium.freecodecamp.com/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project-c0ecbf317089

It gives a detailed and pretty good explanation on how to deploy react application to github pages.