# Why is my create-react-app showing README.md, not index.html?

Tags: reactjs, redux, github-pages, create-react-app

Why is my create-react-app showing README.md, not index.html?

I've run npm run build -> yarn run deploy, checked the file structure multiple times and read the gh-pages docs. Can't find any other thread with the same issue out there.

Thanks.

Comment: What's in your deploy script ? It's not built-in, see [available scripts](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#available-scripts)

Comment: Did you deployed the build directory ? [doc](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages)

Comment: @GabrielBleu yes thank you for your answer, I did deploy the build directory with "predeploy": "npm run build",
 "deploy": "gh-pages -d build", It just seems to not being able to find the index.html. I've done the same process on other projects where it worked flawless.

Comment: build folder should not contain the README

Comment: the README is not included in the build folder.

Comment: @niknau, Did you try any of the answers below? Did it work for you? If yes, mark it as the answer to help anybody coming here in the future. If no, comment on the answer if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 6):

You can checkout the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment) from `create-react-app` regarding this.

**Add homepage to package.json** .

Open your package.json and add a homepage field for your project:

```
"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app",
```

or for a GitHub user page:

```
"homepage": "https://myusername.github.io",
```

Create React App uses the homepage field to determine the root URL in the built HTML file.

**Install gh-pages and add deploy to scripts in package.json**

Now, whenever you run npm run build, you will see a cheat sheet with instructions on how to deploy to GitHub Pages.

To publish it at https://myusername.github.io/my-app, run:

```
npm install --save gh-pages
```

Alternatively you may use yarn:

yarn add gh-pages
Add the following scripts in your package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
+   "predeploy": "npm run build",
+   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
```

The predeploy script will run automatically before deploy is run.

If you are deploying to a GitHub user page instead of a project page you'll need to make two additional modifications:

First, change your repository's source branch to be any branch other than master.
Additionally, tweak your package.json scripts to push deployments to master:

```
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
-   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
+   "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",
```

**Deploy the site by running npm run deploy**

Then run:

```
npm run deploy
```

Step 4: Ensure your project’s settings use gh-pages
Finally, make sure GitHub Pages option in your GitHub project settings is set to use the gh-pages branch:

Comment: GitHub project settings is set to use the gh-pages branch. this is where i was wrong. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The most common mistake is when our GitHub Pages option in your GitHub project settings is set to use the master branch instead of gh-pages.

Just Change it to the gh-pages branch and you are good to go!

see below for example:
[gh-pages branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIZhN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have solved this issue already but I had the same problem with `gh-pages` and CRA deploy not working for github user pages (your root page, not project pages).

What I did was change my "deploy" line to `"deploy": "mv build/* ./* && rmdir build"`, since GitHub **user** pages **only builds from master**. This places all of your build files in the topmost directory of your repo. Push to master and your page should be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
Settings-> Github Pages -> Source 
change source from master branch to gh-pages branch.

This will surely help you .
Ping me in case you encounter any other doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. make sure you change the source from master branch to gh-pages branch.
2. If you don't have a README.md file, create one.