# GitHub pages only showing ReadMe file?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to host my webpages into Github pages but for some reason it seems to only show my Readme file.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/InquisitiveDev2016/InquisitiveDev2016.github.io

Website:

https://inquisitivedev2016.github.io/

Comment: I was having the same problem when I first created my index.html in the root of my project, and this answer helped me to realize I simply needed to wait a few minutes and try again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678354/2604813

Answer (score 39, accepted):

GitHub Pages is doing what it is designed to do: hosting the contents of that repository.

The root of the question asker's repository only contained a single file (`README.md`). So there isn't an easy way to navigate to the other pages, e.g. `repo/website/webpage.html`.

Consider moving your web content into the root of your repository and renaming your default page to `index.md` or `index.html`, depending what type of file it is. (By convention the default page of most websites is called `index.html`, and this is what GitHub Pages will show by default if it exists.)

Comment: In case it might help someone...I had to move all my build files including index.html to the root folder to get it working

Answer (score 22):

Github gives you multiple choices where it takes it sources from. By default its the root of the master branch, which will use the `README.md` in case there is no `index.html`.

But you can also switch to the `docs/` folder in your repository settings. With that you can put the `index.html` under the `docs/` folder.

See [image]

Comment: How do I add the index.html to the "docs" folder? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: You usually checkout the project, add the file, commit and push! Checkout regular `git` https://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I had to choose the branch `gh-pages/root` in Pages settings on GitHub.

Comment: It worked for me. By default, it was ```main/root``` but the react app was deployed to ```gh-pages/root``` which I did by ```npm i gh-pages``` and changing it to ```gh-pages/root``` in github pages settings updated the deployment.

Comment: This answer is so underrated. You saved my day!

Comment: Very happy to read this, Bidisha! Glad I could help

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar situation when deploying a static React app from *create-react-app* (so **index.html** was **in /public** instead of root) with *gh-pages* npm package.

I had to **select a gh-pages as a branch** and **/docs as a folder** at GitHub Project -> Settings -> Pages -> Folder/Branch dropdowns. It wasn't intuitive since I didn't have /docs anywhere in my project files, but I'm glad that it eventually worked!

Comment: This is quite helpful for me, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Create an index.html in the root and insert the line

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; url=public/index.html">
```

Or so it worked for me with a Vue CLI project I had this trouble with.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to access to index.html,
try to write
`https://your-github-deploy-address/index.html`

so just add '/index.html' at the end of the address!
(this is how I solved my case)

Answer (score 2):

For me, this solution solves the issue:https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

Open the package.json file, add two properties as below:

- Add a homepage property in this format*: https://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}

- For a project site, that's the format. For a user site, the format is: https://{username}.github.io. You can read more about the homepage property in the "GitHub Pages" section of the create-react-app documentation.

  ```
    {
      "name": "my-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
    + "homepage": "https://gitname.github.io/react-gh-pages",
      "private": true,
  ```

- Add a predeploy property and a deploy property to the scripts object in :

  ```
    "scripts": {
    +   "predeploy": "npm run build",
    +   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to overcome this is put the index.html file in the outermost folder along with the readme.md

Answer (score 1):

Please change the HTML file to `index.html`. This simple thing had me struggling for 6 hours to find this.
My HTML name before was `base.html`; this shows the read me file only.
After changing to `index.html` the file opened without any problems.

Comment: This is great but how do you get the index.html file to use themes?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following URL in your browser with the necessary changes:

```
https://<username>/github.io/<repo>/<filePathOnGithubToIndex.html>
```

For example, if you can find another repo that is using pages to do link to the demo you will see the path to the html file in the URL. This is mine:

```
https://calebkrauter.github.io/491-sprite-animation-tutorial/Empty--GameEngine-main/index.html
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The steps to resolve this issue is from best practice is to go the your project folder. You should change what ever you named your root or initial page to `index.html` as mentioned above. Then open your project in git bash on your system, perform your normal git steps like,

- `git add`
- `git commit -m " change to index.html"`
- `git push origin master` {depending on what you named your root branch}

Then go to settings and there you go (wow wow)
after one or two refresh, your site will be live

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the docs folder was moved to .gitignore automatically. You have to delete docs from .gitignore, commit and push.

Answer (score 0):

Change the GitHub Pages source to `gh-pages` with folder as `/(root)`

[image]

Comment: I'd say this answer has been repeated multiple times already in this question, so it may be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Please up-vote those answers/comments, as the accepted answer of this post is not correct/working

Comment: Yes I absolutely try and up vote as much as I can, was simply just making an observation.  I would disagree that the accepted answer isn't correct, the concept still applies, just the link is no longer working. I did put in an edit to remove that broken link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Github  is looking into root folder and displaying readme.md file
.Append  SiteUrl given by github  with the  path to index.html file . so github pages start rendering your index.html file.

[Where to get site Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIZLx.png)

In my case my complete Url will be
https://userName.github.io/RepoName/src/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of the steps above and was still seeing my README when I navigated to the deployed site, so I removed a forward slash from the end of the "homepage" in my package.json and that finally did the trick:    `"homepage": "https://{gitname}.github.io/{react-app}/"`     --->
`"homepage": "https://{gitname}.github.io/{react-app}"`

for reference/further context for debugging, my application is set to deploy from the `/root` directory of the `gh-pages` branch and my `index.html` is in my `/public` folder

Answer (score -1):

To summer up, if your repository does not have an Index.html it will show the ReadMe file.
Thus in order to correct it all you need to do is add an index.html or index.md file to your folder and use that as main.
From there all the others will be access through a link on this page. Similarly to a webpage.