# only readme.md is showing on github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, github-for-windows

This is a react js app.I want index.html (which is in public folder by default) as my root folder or any link to navigate index.html
here is my github page :-https://impratikprtk.github.io/almostthere/
and this is my repository :- https://github.com/impratikprtk/almostthere

Comment: The simplest solution is to follow the official guide. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages

Comment: Github pages will serve either from the `/docs` folder on master branch (__not__ `/public`) or from the root folder of either `master` branch a branch called `gh-pages`. https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to make the active branch to be the gh-pages branch, and also from the settings' options tab make the Source branch to also be gh-pages branch.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all files from repo
2. Build your project
3. Add all files are directories inside build to the repo

Hope it works !!

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer here to be much more helpful: [GitHub pages only showing ReadMe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919200/github-pages-only-showing-readme-file) . My site was showing the readme file because I had my source as master, and when I thought I was deploying for master, I was actually deploying to my remote with the `gh-pages` branch which turned out to be much cleaner anyways. When it was reading from master, it didn't see an index so it showed the `README.md` file by default.

I was deploying from a create react app. I didn't realize that running `gh-pages -d build` actually created the `gh-pages` branch on your remote (GitHub) and pushed to it exactly as needed automatically. That said, all I had to do to fix this problem was to change my source for pages to be the `gh-pages` branch.

1. Set your source on the GitHub repository. I.e.

   > Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the gh-pages branch.
2. Add to your scripts in `package.json` the `deploy` and `predeploy`

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",     // <--- this and
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"  // <--- that
  },
```

3. Deploy your app. `yarn deploy` assuming you made the script as above.
4. Log into GitHub, go to your repository, and check out the `gh-pages` branch that should have been created for you. It takes a couple minutes to update on the actual website, so this is a good first place to check to see that the deployment is working.

[image]
Note.. The documentations mention an initial deploy.. but I can see when I run `yarn deploy` that it actually runs `yarn build` without me doing it first.. so I don't seem to need to run the "predeploy". Would love a comment here about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

1. make sure that to change source from master branch to gh-pages branch.
2. If you don't have a README.md file, create one at the gh-pages branch.

this should work!