# Github live previews readme instead of index.html in the /dist/ folder

Tags: javascript, github, webpack, readme, live-preview

**Context**: working on a simple todo list app as part of the Odin Project. I'm on an assignment where we must assemble this project using webpack, but no other frameworks (just vanilla js).

**What I expect to happen**: my live preview shows up successfully when I push to main. I am trying to finish up the todo list app via webpack.

**What happens instead:** Instead of previewing my app, my github live preview *only shows the readme file instead*.

**What I have tried**: When I google the issue, most people who have had this problem say that it is because of either not having an index.html file at all (which I do) or suggest moving it to your root. But webpack puts the packaged file into /dist, and that worked just fine with my restaurant project, so I'm not sure what is wrong here.
I have also tried to update the readme to *link* to the index.html [as this user did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53416429/11309195) in a similar question, only with `permalink: ./dist/index.html`, but doing this for my code just made the live preview 404 entirely.

Link to Repo: https://github.com/manski117/todo-list-app-project

Link to what is *supposed* to be the live preview: https://manski117.github.io/todo-list-app-project/

Comment: Did you choose `dist` folder in github pages settings?

Comment: I don't have that option. I thought to do this intuitively but I only have the choices of `root` or `docs` when I am in the pages setting.

Comment: @manski Yes, that is what I just put in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see your [build](https://github.com/manski117/todo-list-app-project/actions/runs/3752270466/jobs/6374232045) uses Jekyll.

It is better to use the official [`actions/starter-workflows` `pages/jekyll.yml`](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/jekyll.yml) action.

See [Jekyll GitHub Action](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/github-actions/), and add it in `.github/workflows`, with the source of your site directly at the root folder. Including a `_config.yml` to set at least the title.

But if your webapp should not use Jekyll, then chose one of the others [starter workflows](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/tree/main/pages), or adapt one to your own application.

---

See also "[Configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)"

You can directly publish a built content:

> The source branch can be any branch in your repository, and the source folder can either be the root of the repository (`/`) on the source branch or a `/docs` folder on the source branch.

So no "`dist`".

Comment: If you build everything locally, you can also just disable Jekyll by creating an empty `.nojekyll` file in the publishing source directory, without using actions to deploy. It looks like the publishing source is set to the root directory instead of `dist`, though.

Comment: Is there a way to change it? So that the publishing source is set to dist instead of root?

Comment: @manski It depends what framework you are using to build your site. Jekyll? Something else?

Comment: @manski I have edited my answer to reference a publication source for your GitHub Pages site: `/` or `/docs/` folder only, no `/dist/`.

Comment: No framework to my knowledge. I'm not really supposed to be using a framework yet. I'm literally just following the steps directly from the guides on webpack's website as I am extremely new to using it and trying to keep it as simple as possible. I've never even heard of Jekyll until just now.

Comment: @manski OK. That is why I have edited my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminW. you say the empty .nojekyll file goes in the publishing directory. Would that be the root directory or would it be /dist?

Comment: @manski As I mentioned: no dist. / or docs only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250594/discussion-between-manski-and-vonc).

Comment: Update: tried adding a blank .nojekyll file to my source branch. Also separately tried just deleting the readme file. Both give 404 error.