# How to have link of a directory in Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

Suppose I have in 1 file and 1 folder in my repository :-

1. index.html
2. folder

Folder contains again 1 file namely :

1. work.html

Now I want to open folder website with link only of

```
username.github.io/repositoryname/folder
```

Not as

```
username.github.io/repositoryname/folder/work.html
```

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: This should be the default behavior. For eg. http://bajal.github.io/stuff/index.htm and http://bajal.github.io/stuff both work

Comment: what if the file name is another than index.html ? sorry unable to explain it properly @Bajal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `username.github.io/repositoryname/folder/work.html` from `username.github.io/repositoryname/folder` by adding a blank `index.html` file inside `repositoryname/folder/` and adding the following line to it:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0" url="http://username.github.io/repositoryname/folder/work.html" />
```

---

Solution was originally posted by **@DavidJacquel** for a [different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320356/can-i-have-my-github-pages-index-html-in-a-subfolder-of-the-repository#25327759) (load main user site from a subfolder `index.html`) but the approach should work with this issue too.