# Doxygen : link to a Related Page

Tags: documentation, doxygen

Say I have a page, in the Related Pages section, named states.md.
Now, in the doc of a specific method, I want to tell users to go see that file for more details, like "See states.md", with an hyperlink to the page.

The problem is, I have no problem generating the link (I can use the `\ref` command like `See the \ref states.md "states.md"`, but it seems to work the same if I just write the name of the file), however the link goes to a empty and useless page rather than the actual page :

[image: Empty page titled "doc_files/states.md File Reference"]

If I "manually" go to the Related Pages tab, states.md appears in the list, if I click on it from here I can see the content of the file.
How can I make Doxygen generate a link to the actual content of my file, like it appears in the Related Pages tab ?

Comment: Form the image I can see that you are using doxygen version 1.9.3 (good that is the latest release). To be able to give some advise what are the first few lines in the `states.md` is there e.g. a `\page` command or does the first line start wit `#` (so indicating a page?

Comment: No, there isn't anything Doxygen-related in states.md (you can find the file here if you want : https://github.com/TwilCynder/kuribrawl/blob/master/c%2B%2B/doc_files/states.md
I thought it was not a problem since Doxygen still detects states.md as a page, and includes it in the Related Pages section

Comment: Can't you use e.g. `[states.md](md_states.html)`?

Comment: Small complicating factor is the dub directories you use. Looks like: `[states.md](md_doc_files_states.html)` and `[states.md](states.md)` work.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think about that. `[states.md](states.md)` links to the empty page, but ` [states.md](md_doc_files_states.html)` works just fine? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can add an *anchor* in the headline of markdown and link it directly. This is more clean then linking to the created html file. See [official doc](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_page_header).

Here is an examlple:

doit.md:

```
# Specific Information on doIt() {#doit_specific}

- First do this
- Then that
- And finish up
```

Then you can link it in your doxygen. e.g. doIt.h:

```
//! Does it
//!
//! See \ref doit_specific "specific information".
//!
void doIt();
```

Note: You can also just `\ref doit_specific` and it will use the headline as the text.

Additional info: Make sure, the markdown page appears in the related page sections. If it does not, you need to edit the doxygen settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9522667/4675668