# Hide file in doxygen file list

Tags: c#, html, doxygen

We have a file, 'documentation.cs', that we don't want shown in our Doxygen file list. What should I add to our config or the file to hide it from the file list?

[image: We want this gone]

Comment: When it is about removing the entire file look at EXCLUDE. When it is about routines inside the file have a look at \if,  \cond and EXCLUDE_PATTERNS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also simply change the filename do a `.dox`, `.doc` or `.txt` extension. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052036/how-to-include-custom-files-in-doxygen/6336368#6336368):

> There are 3 possible extensions which doxygen treats as additional documentation files: .dox, .txt, and .doc.
>   Files [with] such extension are hidden from the file index. Inside the file you need to put one or more C/C++ style comment blocks.

So rename 'documentation.cs' to 'documentation.dox', but leave the C-style comments inside. (assuming that's what you use - not sure why you decided to add the .cs extension, it doesn't seem like it's actually a C# source file)

Make sure you leave the file in the current directory (if INPUT is left empty) or add it to a directory included in the  [`INPUT`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input) setting.

**EDIT**: According to [this](http://entrenchant.blogspot.com/2009/09/doxygen-gotchas.html) webpage you may have to add `FILE_PATTERNS += *.dox` to your Doxyfile. I don't know if the file extensions are automatically supported nowadays or not but they weren't when the blog was written.

Answer (score 2):

The [Doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude) for EXCLUDE states:

> The EXCLUDE tag can be used to specify files and/or directories that should be excluded from the INPUT source files. This way you can easily exclude a subdirectory from a directory tree whose root is specified with the INPUT tag. 
>   Note that relative paths are relative to the directory from which doxygen is run.

So you can add this line to your doxygen configuration file to remove `documentation.cs`:

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = documentation.cs
# EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = */documentation.cs
```

And then if you wanted to hide more files...

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS += another_file.cs
```

This also works for entire directories.

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS += */directory/*
```

Comment: This also works fine but your other solution is easier. Thanks for being #SOreadytohelp `:-)`